# Installing Spring Boot CLI on Mac using homebrew does not register the command-line completion scripts

Tags: spring, macos, spring-boot, homebrew, spring-cli

I installed `Spring Boot CLI` on my Mac using `Homebrew`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.installing.cli.completion):

`If you install the Spring Boot CLI by using Homebrew or MacPorts, the command-line completion scripts are automatically registered with your shell.`

So in my terminal, I expect to type `spring` then hit `TAB` to see options. I don't. How could I get the completion scripts to work/register?

Comment: Do other Homebrew-related completions work? If not, you probably need to configure your shell to use them: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Homebrew` completions available in `bash` as described in [the Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-bash):

> Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` (or, if it doesn’t exist, `~/.profile`):

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$(brew --prefix)"
  if [[ -r "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]]; then
    source "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
  else
    for COMPLETION in "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/bash_completion.d/"*; do
      [[ -r "$COMPLETION" ]] && source "$COMPLETION"
    done
  fi
fi
```